# How to have alert for the Kafka Connector down for Snowflake

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

How to have the alerts in the system for the Kafka connector is down with Snowflake database?

**Current producer.properties are:**

```
bootstrap.servers =XX.XX.XX.XX0: 9092,XX.XX.XX.XX1: 9092,XX.XX.XX.XX2: 9092
compression.type = none
```

**Errors seen in connect.logs in logs directory: with some dates=**

1st

`[2022 - 06 - 20 14: 52: 10, 239] WARN[Producer clientId = producer - 2] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition connect - status - 4 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader.For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition..Going to request metadata update now(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender: 628)`

2nd:

`[2022 - 06 - 20 14: 52: 09, 836] INFO[Worker clientId = connect - 1, groupId = connect - cluster] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotCoordinator**Exception: This is  not the correct coordinator (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: 456)`

3rd:

```
[2022 - 05 - 30 02: 19: 28, 609] INFO[Consumer clientId = connector - consumer - file - stream - distributed - 0, groupId = connect - file - stream - distributed] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequired**Exception**: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: 456)
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

INFORMATION:

1. Details of the topic and its replication, partition and leader
   [Kafka, Zookeeper `deploy@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX bin] $. /kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper XX.XX.XX.XX:2181 --topic 'topic_name' --describe`

   > ```
   > Topic: uat.product.topic        PartitionCount: 6      
   > ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
   >          Topic: uat.product.topic        Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
   >          Topic: uat.product.topic        Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
   >          Topic: uat.product.topic        Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
   >          Topic: uat.product.topic        Partition: 3    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
   >          Topic: uat.product.topic        Partition: 4    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
   >          Topic: uat.product.topic        Partition: 5    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
   > ```
2. server.properties

> ```
> offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
> transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
> ```

3. consumer.properts

> ```
> bootstrap.servers=XX.XX.XX.001:9092,XX.XX.XX.002:9092,XX.XX.XX.003:9092
> group.id=connect-cluster 
> auto.offset.reset=beginning
> ```

What should be the values of these parameters in the `producer.properties` for all 3 kafka nodes:

1. Please guide as I am loosing some of records from source to the
   target, due to which there is mismatch in the records within
   target-database(lesser records) as compared to source database.
2. As these records are getting disappeared due to these above
   1st, 2nd and 3rd errors.
3. Because in cluster, it's common I think with
   varying load and increase no of topics.
4. Going ahead how I can take care if there is increase in topics
   and even increase of data load?
5. What should be the values of these parameters in the
   producer.properties for all 3 kafka nodes,so my messages are minimum send to the stream and gets insertion confirmation
   `enable.idempotence`
   `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`
   `retries`
   `retry.backoff.ms`
   `delivery.timeout.ms`
6. Currently I have 3 node system

Comment: Do you mean an alert in Kafka or an alert in Snowflake or an alert in some overall monitoring system? Snowflake has no generic alerting mechanism

Comment: Kafka Connect also has no altering built in

Answer (score 0):

If Snowflake is down, or you get some network / query exception, you should expect connector logs to indicate the problem.

You'll therefore need a generic log aggregation framework that can read this and generate alerts. Splunk or Elasticsearch are the most commonly used products for this, in my experience.

Otherwise, you can poll the /status API endpoint of the connector and look for failed tasks and programmatically generate alerts to whatever API you want, such as PagerDuty or Slack

Comment: Thats good to hear dude, but there is nothing practical documentation available. And some are costing money and some don't have the documentation at all easily available. Now going back, we can do this through Python scripting then even thats too hard to figure out the status out the Kafka logs

Comment: What more documentation do you need than 1) `grep Exception connect.log` 2) if has data, create alert in your own altering system? You can further adjust your log filtering if that's too noisy. There's nothing for this built-in to Kafka, Snowflake, or Connect. And like I said, you should query the Connect API, not the "Kafka logs" to clearly find the running status

Comment: You are absolutely correct Circk...! I have updated my main problem statement. Please help.

Comment: @AustinJackson Thanks, but I don't think that changes my answer. Connect has no alerting built-in, so you need to send the logs somewhere else, or poll the `/status` endpoint and count task failures, then send a notification elsewhere

Comment: Plus, Connect never uses `producer.properties` file, so I dont really understand the last part of your question

Comment: True, there is nothing alerting built-in, but as you said the Exception was a keyword which I utilize to find the fault. As we should have a look at the Idempotent Producer for tweaking the Producer configs. It allows to properly and efficiently guarantee ordering and no data loss.

Comment: Main goal is no data loss as thats my main motive

Comment: @Austin I recall seeing a Kafka JIRA saying that sink consumers weren't exactly once. Only the S3 and HDFS connectors could guarantee it because they used a write-ahead-log, for example. The idempotent producer will only guarantee data gets to the broker, not guarantee data won't be lost or duplicated on its way to Snowflake (there's no Kafka producer involved in that step). Also, you have 3 brokers, so you should strongly consider not having one replica for any topic if you truly care about no data loss

Comment: One is replication factor to be enabled. Any other method, which will help me to not to loose a single record....

Comment: `acks=all` will guarantee from the producer that the data is available on all replicas. Again, once data leaves Kafka, there is no guarantee it will not be dropped or duplicated. De-duplication completely depends on the consumer.

Comment: Well then anything consumer parameter, that can guarantee. Because its something we don't want to loose anything, where everything is crucial

Comment: @AustinJackson There is no consumer property that will control a database client, for example. I assume you've fully read this? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-overview.html#fault-tolerance

Comment: I did the acks=all, offsets.topic.replication.factor=3,transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3 ,transaction.state.log.min.isr=3                                                                                                                                                
getting the error
[2022-07-01 21:43:45,792] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CoordinatorNotAvailableException: The coordinator is not available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:456)
Pls guide

Comment: max.poll.interval.ms=300000
session.timeout.ms=10000